# Create auto generated methods in your class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, auto-generate

I am writing some classes in Eclipse in Java, and I would like to know how to generate auto generate code.

For example, if I have abstract class and I expect to be use as extends class I would like to force override some classes.

I see that same classes has this implemented, and if you extend from them eclipse auto generate empty methods for override.

Comment: Marko Zadravec, when you select `New -> Class` there comes option for declaring `super class` and `interfaces`. just `browse/add` your classes/interfaces in relevant text boxes and you will get auto generated unimplemented methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have such classes:

```
public abstract class A {
    public void implementMe();
}
```

... and:

```
public class B extends A {
}
```

In **Eclipse**, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> on the name of class that needs to *override* some methods and select *"Add unimplemented methods"* in the contextual menu that will show up.

```
// Ctrl - 1 with your cursor here
//           v    
public class B extends A {
}
```

It will generate for you the following:

```
public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void implementMe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```